# Cesium terrain not loading from CDN

Tags: cesiumjs

I created a custom terrain using Cesium Terrain Builder docker and am trying to serve it from a standard CDN or cloud bucket. I've uploaded all the terrain folders to the CDN and they are correctly accessible, e.g.

- `https://mycdn.com/terrains/terrain1/layer.json`
- `https://mycdn.com/terrains/terrain1/0/0/0.terrain`
- `https://mycdn.com/terrains/terrain1/0/1/0.terrain`

and so on - I can access all the files from a browser.
But, when trying to access them from my Cesium app, I don't see the terrain (i.e. transparent environment). Checking the network tab in Chrome, I can see layer.json and the root terrain files have been accessed successfully. There are no errors in the console log. It just doesn't show up.

Any idea why?
p.s. same data loads fine from a Cesium Terrain Server container...

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause. The tiles are gzipped. The CDN need to be configured so that every tile file is served with `Content-Encoding: gzip` header.

Once that's done, terrain loads and I can see all tiles get loaded in chrome (not just the root tiles)